# Chrome DevTools : Reorder Watch Expressions

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I'm using chrome canary and would like to know if it is possible to reorder the watch expressions in the right side panel of dev tools.
I'm guessing the values are stored in some config file somewhere but can't seem to find it.

Comment: Is there a real life scenario where this can be useful?

Comment: I'm using devtools as my main ide these days - so I like to change the order of the watches depending on what I'm working on.

Comment: @KonradDzwinel Just now, when repeatedly stepping through how a series of assignments in a framework object's attributes played out, I wanted a bunch of watch expressions for the attributes (whose assignment statements each in turn affected the subsequent assignments) to have have a logical order for clarity, which brought me to this Q.  It seems to me like an odd bit of UI neglect that one *can't* just mouse-drag the expressions up/down in the list to change the order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to change order of "Watch expressions" in the "Sources" panel is by removing them and adding them back again in the desired order.

---

The more complex solution, goes like this:

- detach DevTools window (**A**)
- using keyboard shortcut open another (**B**) DevTools window (<kbd>F12</kbd> or <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>opt</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>) for window **A**
- in window **B** go to the "Resources" tab
- select "Local Storage"
- find list of watch expressions (look for `watchExpressions` key)
- edit value by clicking on it
- close window **B**
- reload window **A** (e.g. by closing DevTools and opening them again)

*Demonstration:*

[image: changing order of watch expressions in Chrome DevTools]

Comment: The more complex solution worked a treat. Very useful, thanks.

Comment: I'd love to ask whether enabling cold folding in the devtools sources Codemirror is possible. But I have a feeling it is not.